# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql

[image]

Those are mine table "tempo" attributes ... the problem is that when i try to do an insert query, the browser told me that :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'01-01-12 0:2:41 AM','29','Via D Alviano fr' at line 1

The query is

```
INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'01-01-12 0:1:0 AM','29',' Via Italo Svevo, 38 34145 Trieste','0','0');
```

This is the string I execute as a query

> INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:1:0','29',' Via Italo Svevo, 38 34145 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:2:41','29','Via D Alviano fr. 39 34144 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:2:56','29','Via Bartolomeo D Alviano, 86, Trieste, 34144 TS','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:3:1','29','FER-29015, 34144 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:1:5','29','Via Bartolomeo D Alviano, 13, 34144 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:3:0','29','Via Leon Battista Alberti, 6 34144 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:3:0','29','Via Leon Battista Alberti, 6 34144 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:2:0','29','Via Lorenzo Bernini, 6 34137 Trieste','0','0');
>   INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:6:32','29','Piazza C.Goldoni 11 (bar Venier), Trieste, 34122 TS','0','0');

PHP code :

```
 <?php
  $queryOrario = $_POST['queryField'];
  echo $queryOrario;
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','trieste_trasporti');
  if($db->connect_errno>0){
   die('Errore Numero ' .$db->connect_error);
  }
  if ($db->query($queryOrario) === TRUE) {
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $queryOrario . "<br>" . $db->error;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Odd, you insert Via Italo Svevo, but the error message is having issues with Via D Alviano...

Comment: Valid values for a tables DATETIME column are `YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS:SS` so your `AM` will cause an issue

Comment: seems you missed  the column name for insert clause

Comment: @scaisEdge They are not required, although I always add then so I cannot get things in the wrong column

Comment: @RiggsFolly   thanks  .. i also always add so  ..then is only a good practice ..

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have just changed it in the right format, but the error is still there ...You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:2:41','29','Via D Alviano fr.' at line 1

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 00:02:41','29','Via Italo Svevo, 38 34145 Trieste','0','0');`

Comment: Refresh the page, I made a small typo that I edited

Comment: I have just tried to execute the queries manually, and it works... so i think i have done something wrong with the php

Comment: It would have been useful to add the PHP code if that is what you are using to execute this query!

Comment: I generate the query in javascript because i get the data from API asyc calls, then I need to execute the query .

Comment: Like I said, show us the PHP code that you are using to submit these queries to the database

Comment: Maybe a good idea to show the javascript as well as that will need amending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> INSERT INTO tempo VALUES (null,'2017-01-01 0:1:0','29',' Via Italo Svevo, 38 34145 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:2:41','29','Via D Alviano fr. 39 34144 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:3:55','29','Via Bartolomeo D Alviano, 86, Trieste, 34144 TS','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:3:1','29','FER-29015, 34144 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:1:5','29','Via Bartolomeo D Alviano, 13, 34144 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:3:0','29','Via Leon Battista Alberti, 6 34144 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:2:0','29','Via Lorenzo Bernini, 6 34137 Trieste','0','0'),(null,'2017-01-01 0:7:28','29','Piazza C.Goldoni 11 (bar Venier), Trieste, 34122 TS','0','0')

I have found the answer to my question ... you just have to put everything in a single query. thanks to everyone who tryed to help me :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do multiple queries within a single "query" command in php. Use "multi_query" instead. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Use comments sections for suggestions. An answer must always be well-researched and substantive. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your comment, and thank you for the link. I would have made a comment and tried to do so, however, being new, found that I cannot until I have 10 reputation points. So I gave an answer which I believe is beneficial to solve the problem. I have improved the answer by providing an appropriate link.